# Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I`m building a dashboard application using ASP.NET where users can change positions of the widgets; i used jquery sortables for that. The widgets are ascx (asp.net usercontrols) which are added dynamically to the page. Every event in the widget works fine on if the user have not changed the positions of the widgets but if the position is changed i get this error.

**Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'xxx'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.**

Here is the code of one of the widgets and user can add multiple instances of it.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
   <div class="setting" >
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtwidgettitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <div id="settingfooter">
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnSave" runat="server" onclick="lnkbtnSave_Click">Save</asp:LinkButton>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtncancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
      </div>
   </div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkbtnSave" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div class="pcontent">   
  <asp:Literal ID="ltrtwcontent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

And the code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ltrtwcontent.Text = jqPlotHelper.RenderChart(CurrentWidgetInstance.Id.ToString());
}
protected void lnkbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DashboardServices d = new DashboardServices();
    CurrentWidgetInstance.Title = txtwidgettitle.Text;
    CurrentWidgetInstance.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    d.SaveOrUpdateWidgetInstance(CurrentWidgetInstance);

}
```

on the aspx page loading the controls i first have a container which is added dynamically and the container will add the the widget instances (the ascx controls)

Code on the page

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetBasePageVAR(DashboredPageGuid);
        if (this.UsrPage != null)
        {
            phltabs.Controls.Add(LoadDashboardTab());
        }
    }
    public HtmlGenericControl LoadDashboardTab()
    {
       HtmlGenericControl mainList = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
       mainList.Attributes["Id"] = "tabs";
       foreach (WidgetInstance widgetInst in CurrentDashboardTab.WidgetInstances)
       {
         HtmlGenericControl headerList = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
         WidgetContainerBaseControl widgetContainer = LoadControl("~/Dashboard/WidgetContainer.ascx") as WidgetContainerBaseControl;
         widgetContainer.SetControlVAR(widgetInst);
         headerList.Controls.Add(widgetContainer);
         mainList.Controls.Add(headerList);
       }
       return mainList;
    }
```

and on WidgetContainer.ascx

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LoadWidgetInstance();
}
public void LoadWidgetInstance()
{
  WidgetControl widget = LoadControl(CurrentWidgetInstance.Widget.Url) as WidgetControl;
  widget.ID = "wid_" + CurrentWidgetInstance.Id;
  this.phlcontent.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Where is that error thrown?

Comment: I caught the error on js debugger(firebug). save event will not respond once a widget position is changed.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I have posted the code

Comment: Could you show where you are dynamically loading the ascx objects into the page?  Or is that what that "RenderChart" call does in Page_Load?

Comment: @jadarnel27 the ascx objects are loaded dynamically on Page_Init method. "RenderChart" is just for loading some content; i think it doesnt have any effect on my problem

Comment: Can you show that code from `Page_Init`?  It sounds like the problem may lie there.

Comment: @jadarnel27 i post the the code

Comment: It started working! but can`t explain why. in LoadDashboardTab method after `WidgetContainerBaseControl widgetContainer = LoadControl("~/Dashboard/WidgetContainer.ascx") as WidgetContainerBaseControl;` i added ` widgetContainer.ID = "widgetCont_" + widgetInst.Id; ` but then it start throwing this error **Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was..** then when i set the EnableViewState property of the main placeholder control to False everything start working

Answer (score 0):

try this: Add trigger Like this and Remove the one in Asps Page

```
ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1");
sm.RegisterPostBackControl(Button);
```